# create html through DOM, the results only showed up in the console, but not on the web page

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am new to coding. I am trying to create some html by using DOM. I got it work in the console, but for some reason, it only shows `[object HTMLDivElement][object HTMLDivElement][object HTMLDivElement]` on my webpage.

Here is my html:`<div id="all-products"></div>`

Here is my js code :

```
let inventory = [
  ['LA-LG-STICKER', 300, 'Large Sticker', 'images/la-large-sticker-256px.png', 'Show your Launch pride by plastering your laptop with these beautiful die-cut stickers.'],
  ['LA-SM-STICKER', 200, 'Small Sticker', 'images/la-small-sticker-128px.png', "It\'s a tiny Launch sticker. How cute!"],
  ['LA-T-SHIRT', 50, 'T-Shirt', 'images/la-t-shirt-200px.png', '100% Cotton. Makes a great gift.']
]

class Product {
  constructor(id, quantity, name, image, description) {
    this.id = id;
    this.quantity = quantity;
    this.name = name;
    this.image = image;
    this.description = description;
  }

  sell() {
    this.quantity -= 1
    return this.quantity;
  }

  toHTML() {
    let div = document.createElement('div');
    div.className = 'product';
    div.innerHTML += '<h1>Product Name:' + this.name + '</h1>';
    div.innerHTML += '<h5>' + this.quantity + ' In Stock</h5>'
    div.innerHTML += '<img src="' + this.image +'" alt="' + this.name + '" />'
    div.innerHTML += '<h3>Description</h3>'
    div.innerHTML += '<p>' + this.description + '</p>'
    return div;
  }
}

let products = inventory.map(item => {
  return new Product(...item);
})


let element = document.getElementById('all-products');

products.forEach((product) => {
  element.innerHTML += product.toHTML()

})
```

Comment: Can you put your compete HTML code?, the `*ngFor` and how you call `toHTML()`

Comment: so we could provide a precise answer to your problem

Comment: @masterpreenz - It's already there, just scroll down. :)

Answer (score 1):

You're producing a `HTMLElement` and then in the end assigning it to `innerHTML`. That's not going to work, it just converts the `HTMLElement` to a `string` which produces what you see.

Instead, you need to add it to the DOM with [`element.appendChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) or some such. Basically, you need to change just one line:

```
products.forEach((product) => {
  element.appendChild(product.toHTML());
})
```

Alternatively, you can just work with strings all the way - it'll be faster too:

```
toHTML() {
  let ret = '<div class="product">';
  ret += '<h1>Product Name:' + this.name + '</h1>';
  ret += '<h5>' + this.quantity + ' In Stock</h5>';
  ret += '<img src="' + this.image +'" alt="' + this.name + '" />';
  ret += '<h3>Description</h3>';
  ret += '<p>' + this.description + '</p>';
  ret += '</div>';
  return ret;
}
```

For maximum performance there are two more optimizations you can do:

- Instead of repeatedly modifying `element.innerHTML`, gather all the HTML in a single big string and assign it once, when you're done.
- Building long strings piece-by-piece is more efficient when done with arrays. Essentially, instead of `var ret = ""; ret += "piece" + x + "piece"` you go `var ret = []; ret.push("piece", x, "piece");` and in the end do a `ret.join("")` to get it all concatenated in a single big string.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you aren't returning **HTML strings** at all. You are returning a **div (object)** that you have created by using **CreateElement** method.

You only have to change this:

`element.innerHTML += product.toHTML()`

to this:

`element.innerHTML += product.toHTML().innerHTML`

and you will see the **DOM in you document**.

Or...

in your **toHTML()** method, change the return value to this:

`return div.innerHTML;`

but you will lost the element, if you don't create a new one from HTML.

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = s;
```

(the inverted process)

Comment: I think he needs the `<div>` itself too, since he sets a specific class on it. Would also make sense for displaying a list of items.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue comes from this area.

```
toHTML() {
  let div = document.createElement('div');
  div.className = 'product';
  div.innerHTML += '<h1>Product Name:' + this.name + '</h1>';
  div.innerHTML += '<h5>' + this.quantity + ' In Stock</h5>'
  div.innerHTML += '<img src="' + this.image +'" alt="' + this.name + '" />'
  div.innerHTML += '<h3>Description</h3>'
  div.innerHTML += '<p>' + this.description + '</p>'
  return div;
}
```

where you just actually `+= div.innerHTML` you cannot do this this way, you just need to call this once:

```
toHTML() {
  let div = document.createElement('div');
  div.className = 'product';

  // Put them all first in a string
  var childElements = "";
  childElements += '<h1>Product Name:' + this.name + '</h1>';
  childElements += '<h5>' + this.quantity + ' In Stock</h5>';
  childElements += '<img src="' + this.image +'" alt="' + this.name + '" />';
  childElements += '<h3>Description</h3>';
  childElements += '<p>' + this.description + '</p>';

  // then append it
  div.innerHTML = childElements;

  return div;
}
```

UPDATED:

to append properly use `appendChild` not `innerHTML`:

```
let element = document.getElementById('all-products');
products.forEach((product) => {
    element.appendChild(product.toHTML());
})
```

why `appendChild` because you are adding elements one by one through a loop.

hope that helps

Comment: I dunno, it works for me in Chrome just fine. Also, the problem is elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I only changed the last lines (And addeded some images):

```js
let inventory = [
  ['LA-LG-STICKER', 300, 'Large Sticker', 'http://via.placeholder.com/350x150', 'Show your Launch pride by plastering your laptop with these beautiful die-cut stickers.'],
  ['LA-SM-STICKER', 200, 'Small Sticker', 'http://via.placeholder.com/350x150', "It\'s a tiny Launch sticker. How cute!"],
  ['LA-T-SHIRT', 50, 'T-Shirt', 'http://via.placeholder.com/350x150', '100% Cotton. Makes a great gift.']
]

class Product {
  constructor(id, quantity, name, image, description) {
    this.id = id;
    this.quantity = quantity;
    this.name = name;
    this.image = image;
    this.description = description;
  }

  sell() {
    this.quantity -= 1
    return this.quantity;
  }

  toHTML() {
    let div = document.createElement('div');
    div.className = 'product';
    div.innerHTML += '<h1>Product Name:' + this.name + '</h1>';
    div.innerHTML += '<h5>' + this.quantity + ' In Stock</h5>'
    div.innerHTML += '<img src="' + this.image +'" alt="' + this.name + '" />'
    div.innerHTML += '<h3>Description</h3>'
    div.innerHTML += '<p>' + this.description + '</p>'
    return div;
  }
}

let products = inventory.map(item => {
  return new Product(...item);
})


let element = document.getElementById('all-products');

products.forEach((product) => {
  element.append(product.toHTML());

})
```

```html
<div id="all-products"></div>
```

Comment: Note: `.append()` works only in fairly new browsers. IE and Edge don't support it at all. A more compatible alternative in this case would be `.appendChild()`.